# Is there any current way and/or plans to include HTML with CSS styling in a message or card?

Tags: botframework

I've been trying to design a simple bot and wanted some more styling options to make the messages look nicer.

Ideally what I would use would be HTML with CSS but I have not found a way to do that.

I've tried using the adaptive card to get a similar level of control over the formatting, but I didn't see a way to do some simple things like add color or change the font.

Does anyone know if there is a current way to do this or if there are any plans to do so in the future?

Comment: I hope you got this working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's difficult to use just html and css to customize Web Chat's appearance; however, you can create a styleOptions object with your style preferences and pass it as a prop to Web Chat. Here are Web Chat's [default style options](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js) that you can customize, and here is a quick example of some of the style changes you can make.

**Style Options**

```
const styleOptions = {
  botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
  primaryFont: 'cursive',
  userAvatarInitials: 'WC',
  backgroundColor: '#767676',
  sendBoxButtonColor: 'Red'
}

renderWebChat({
  directLine,
  styleOptions
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

For more examples, take a look at the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples) in the Web Chat repo - sample 5 is a good one to reference to get started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was more thinking of formatting the message itself. I.E being able to display html and css as a reply to the user. With a bit more digging a found more documentation on the [adaptive cards](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/AdaptiveCard.html) and it seems to be the best alternative. Thanks anyway!